# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'chosen-rails'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitlab, bundler, unicorn

Why am i getting this error?
When starting gitlab.

```
#  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'chosen-rails'.
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `has?' for Sass::Util:Module
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/urls.rb:5:in `has?'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions/urls.rb:9:in `included'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.5.5/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:632:in `include'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.5.5/lib/sass/script/functions.rb:632:in `include'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions.rb:16:in `<module:Functions>'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions/functions.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass/sass_extensions.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `each'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-0.12.2/lib/compass.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-rails-2.0.0/lib/compass-rails.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/chosen-rails-1.0.0/lib/chosen-rails.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
config.ru:4:in `require'
config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
config.ru:1:in `new'
config.ru:1:in `<main>'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `call'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `block in rails_builder'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `call'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
/home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `load'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:75:in `kernel_load'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:424:in `exec'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:122:in `with_friendly_errors'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:    

  /home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:84:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
  /home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:80:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  /home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
  /home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
  /home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
  /home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
  /home/git/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/config/environment.rb:2:in `require'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:4:in `require'
  config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `eval'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn.rb:48:in `block in builder'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `call'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn_rails:139:in `block in rails_builder'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `call'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:722:in `build_app!'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/unicorn-4.6.3/bin/unicorn_rails:209:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `load'
  /home/git/old-gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/unicorn_rails:23:in `<top (required)>'
```

My environment.
Centos7
Gitlab 6.2.4
ruby 2.0.0p353
git 1.8.3.1

Since the previous environment was broken, I want to recover the data by starting up in the same environment.

The bundle install is over.

Do you have any other necessary information?

please help me.

Comment: See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45269621/phusion-error-undefined-method-has-for-sassutilmodule) SO question.

Comment: @JeroenHeier  Thank you very much.
I moved it.